# React Error: Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am learning the react js and following [this](https://youtu.be/ngc9gnGgUdA) tutorial but whenever I type something in the text field I am getting an error like following.

[image: The error image:]

I am using the material ui.

The code is as following:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
    creator: "",
    title: "",
    message: "",
    tags: "",
    selectedFile: "",
  });

  const classes = useStyles();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventdefault();
    dispatch(createPost(postData));
  };
  return (
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <form
        className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <Typography variant="h6">Creating a Memory</Typography>
        <TextField
          name="creator"
          label="Creator"
          value={postData.creator}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setPostData({ ...postData, creator: e.target.value })
          } />
        //... other fields
        <Button
          className={classes.buttonSubmit}
          type="submit"
          fullWidth >
          submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

The app.js code where Form is getting called in:

```
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
      <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
        <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align="center">
          Memories
        </Typography>
        <img
          className={classes.image}
          src={memories}
          alt="memories"
        />
      </AppBar>
      <Grow in>
        <Container>
          <Grid
            spacing={3}
          >
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
              <Posts />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Form />  //I am calling it here
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </Grow>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

The useState is in the correct order and I am not using the other hooks as well but somehow getting an error.

Comment: Do you have any parent component calling Form?

Comment: Yes, in the app.js file.@RitikBanger

Comment: The problem lies here in app.js->>  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [dispatch]);

Comment: Ok but I don't get it. What is a solution to this? @RitikBanger

Comment: Can you try removing dispatch from dependency and then see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when you call your hooks in loops, conditions, or nested functions.
I think You are calling some kind of hook inside `getPosts()` function. This function is inside `useEffect`, so it will call conditionally, thus error.

Read [this guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: There is no hook inside of getPost(). ```export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = api.fetchPosts();
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_ALL", payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};``` If there is please correct me.

Comment: Try commenting `getPosts()` and see if the error is still there

Comment: Yes, Error is still showing up.